# Show that the series converges for all $0 < a < 3$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

The series is: $\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty \dfrac {n!}{n^n}a^n$

**This is what I have so far:**

Using the ratio test, I have $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac {(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\frac {n^n}{n!}\frac {a^{n+1}}{a^n}\right|=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left\vert a\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}\right)^n\right\vert=\left|\frac {a}{e}\right|$$

For the series to be converging, $$\left\vert\frac {a}{e}\right\vert < 1 \implies-e <a<e$$

I don't think I have done this correctly but I don't see anything wrong with my steps.

Comment: Can you fix the first line? It should be $a^n$, not $a_n$.

Comment: so sorry, i haven't done this formatting before.

Comment: This certainly looks right to me.  If you've made a mistake, I can't find it.  To pick a nit, it's possible that the series converges at $e$ or $-e$ but not for $|a|>e$

Comment: @saulspatz for $|a|=e$ it also diverges by stirling

Comment: "For the series to be converging, $\left\vert\dfrac {a}{e}\right\vert < 1 $" No, that's not correct. The other direction is correct: If the limit is $<1,$ then the series converges.

Comment: @pinklemonade Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is correct and by ratio test we can conclude that

- $|a|<e$ the series converges
- $|a|> e$ the series diverges

moreover since for $a=e$ by [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) $n! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$

$$\dfrac {n!}{n^n}e^n\sim\sqrt{2 \pi n}\to\infty$$

for $|a|=e$ the series also diverges.